# cgi script faild to call another python script

Tags: python

I have a cgi script and it's calling another python script but while running via browser the second script not working.

```
subprocess.Popen([python, 'symantec.py', '-k', "test3.example.com.com.key", '-c', 
                  "test3.example.com.com.csr", '-n', "test3.example.com.com", 
                  '-o', "'IT'", '-p', "war.eagle", '-t', "Server", '-s', "F5", 
                  '-y', "1", '-f', "test3.example.com.com.crt", '-g', "johny", '-l', 
                  "mon", '-e', "johny.mon@example.com.com", '-b', "test3.example.com.com"], 
                  shell=True)
```

Can someone help me to identify ?

Path to second script symantec.py
https://github.com/ericjmcalvin/verisign_purchase_ssl_certificate

Comment: What is in the ```python``` variable? What error did you have? (Other than that, you should set ```shell = False``` if you are using argument list and not a string)

Answer (score 0):

You should first test the command.

```
python symantec.py -k test3.example.com.com.key -c test3.example.com.com.csr -n test3.example.com.com -o 'IT' -p war.eagle -t Server -s F5 -y 1 -f test3.example.com.com.crt -g johny -l mon -e johny.mon@example.com.com -b test3.example.com.com`
```

The script is expecting absolute paths as arguments to `-k` and `-c` arguments. The help specifies:

> -h, --help            show this help message and exit
>
> -k KEY_FILE, --key-file=KEY_FILE
> *Full location* to save key file. REQUIRED.

Once you made sure it is working, call it from your script:

```
command = "python symantec.py -k test3.example.com.com.key -c test3.example.com.com.csr -n test3.example.com.com -o 'IT' -p war.eagle -t Server -s F5 -y 1 -f test3.example.com.com.crt -g johny -l mon -e johny.mon@example.com.com -b test3.example.com.com"
subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=False)
```

Another way to accomplish this is to import the Symantec script and call its main function, providing, naturally, the expected arguments.

Comment: ERROR: Unable to generate OpenSSL key due to the following error: Command '['/usr/bin/openssl', 'genrsa', '-out', 'test3.example.com.key', '2048']' returned non-zero exit status 1                                                                                                                       now i am facing the above error because the script trying to generate one file called  test3.example.com.key and its not  able to generate but if we run the command from command line i am able to generate the file

Comment: Which version of the script are you using? I tried to replicate the error by I see that you are using the `-b` parameter which is not supported by the HEAD version.

Comment: I just modified HEAD version the script to include  SAN, you can remove "-b test3.example.com.com" and even i tried to use HEAD version facing the same error

Comment: Cf. my edit: you need to specify absolute paths. We might not be done troubleshooting...

Comment: if we add absolute paths also script is working fine via console but not working via browser